# How do I find an app that got lost following upgrade to iO6

Tags: upgrade, ios-appstore

I upgraded to iOS6. Something went wrong, and after the upgrade I needed to use an iCloud backup to restore the iPad.

Although almost all my apps came back, one is missing (it would have been in the backup). It was a simple, free color learning app, but one that meant a lot to my kids. The name was very generic, so I can't find it with Google or App Store search. I tried the  "purchased" tabs on each of my accounts in the App Store, and it isn't there.

How do I find the app, or what happened with it? Could it be missing from the "purchased tab" because it is incompatible with ios6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the app was pulled from the App Store for some reason. Based on information from the Stack Overflow question [What happens to my apps after my developer account membership expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires), if a developer stops subscribing to the developer program, their apps are pulled from the App Store, even if they've been paid for by a user. Which means that users should back up any apps that are important to them, especially if they are from smaller developers.

Fortunately I had backed my iPad up, I was able to restore the .ipa file from a backup on another machine using iTunes.

Comment: Even if apps are removed from the store due to the developer's account expiring, the apps will always be available to download from the App Store's purchased list.

Answer (score 1):

New iOS versions never break compatibility with older apps. You could try viewing your purchases in iTunes on your computer. This could be fruitful as the app may have been hidden — to check, go to your account details page (in iTunes) and select "View Hidden Purchases."

Also, consider the possibility that it was downloaded with an Apple ID you haven't thought of. If you're certain it's not on the iPad, you can't find it under Purchased, and neither you nor your kids can remember its name, then it may have been pulled from the App Store. This isn't very likely, though.

Comment: It looks like the apps (I had the same experience with another app) were indeed pulled from the App Store, or the developers' didn't renew their development licenses or something.